# greatest n per group optimization

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions, conditional-aggregation

How can I optimize this SQLite query? It currently takes 31 seconds to run. I want to display the top 10 stock gainers and top 10 stock losers on a web application. The table has 2m rows and should increase ever so slightly each day new price data is available.

If this is not possible, I could create a scheduled task to cache these results to a temp db table or a temp file. Seems like extra work but possible if needed.

```
WITH todayPrices AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT *, row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY CompanyID 
        ORDER BY Date DESC
        ) AS rn
    FROM DimCompanyPrice
    ) a
    WHERE rn = 1 
    ORDER BY CompanyID ASC
    ),
    yestPrices AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT *, row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY CompanyID 
        ORDER BY Date DESC
        ) AS rn
    FROM DimCompanyPrice
    ) a
    WHERE rn = 2 
    ORDER BY CompanyID ASC
    )
    SELECT todayPrices.CompanyID, 100.0 * (todayPrices.CloseAdjusted-yestPrices.CloseAdjusted) / yestPrices.CloseAdjusted AS gain
    FROM todayPrices
    INNER JOIN yestPrices on todayPrices.CompanyID=yestPrices.CompanyID
    ORDER BY gain DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

I would like some input in regards to what would be the best approach to getting this to perform better. Any input would be appreciated.

Results of `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`:

```
id  parent  notused  detail
3   0       0   MATERIALIZE 2
5   3       0   CO-ROUTINE 1
8   5       0   CO-ROUTINE 6
11  8       0   SCAN TABLE DimCompanyPrice
36  8       0   USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
62  5       0   SCAN SUBQUERY 6
134 3       0   SCAN SUBQUERY 1 AS a
163 3       0   USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
174 0       0   MATERIALIZE 4
176 174     0   CO-ROUTINE 3
179 176     0   CO-ROUTINE 7
182 179     0   SCAN TABLE DimCompanyPrice
207 179     0   USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
233 176     0   SCAN SUBQUERY 7
305 174     0   SCAN SUBQUERY 3 AS a
334 174     0   USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
345 0       0   SCAN SUBQUERY 4
357 0       0   SEARCH SUBQUERY 2 USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (CompanyID=?)
382 0       0   USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

Comment: Start with using [the sqlite3 command line tool's `.expert` command](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#index_recommendations_sqlite_expert_) to suggest indexes.

Comment: And drop the `ORDER BY`s from the CTEs.

Comment: Have a single CTE with WHERE rn = 1 or rn = 2 and then just self join that CTE in your final SELECT

Comment: Neither of the recommendations to drop the `ORDER BY` or use a single `CTE` improved the performance.

Comment: You'll need to update your question with the results of running EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN for the SQL statement you'd like help with. If the SQL statement is not the one already in your question (because you've updated it with one of the previous suggestions) then please include the SQL statement that corresponds to the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN

Comment: My query hasn’t changed so the query in my question is still relevant. The solutions didn’t improve the performance so changes were not warranted. What do you mean by EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN?

Comment: Explain Query Plan: https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html

Comment: Updated the question with the requested output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a query that uses conditional aggregation to calculate the column `gain`.
For this you will need a single table scan to rank the rows of each company based on date, then filter out the rows with ranking greater than 2 and finally aggregation:

```
SELECT CompanyId,
       100 * (MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN CloseAdjusted END) / MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN CloseAdjusted END) - 1) gain
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyId ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
  FROM DimCompanyPrice
)
WHERE rn <= 2
GROUP BY CompanyId
ORDER BY gain DESC;
```

But if by *today* and *yesterday* you actually mean the current date and the previous date, you could also do it with this query:

```
SELECT CompanyId,
       100 * (MAX(CASE WHEN Date = CURRENT_DATE THEN CloseAdjusted END) / MAX(CASE WHEN Date = Date(CURRENT_DATE, '-1 day') THEN CloseAdjusted END) - 1) gain
FROM DimCompanyPrice
WHERE Date >= Date(CURRENT_DATE, '-1 day')
GROUP BY CompanyId;
```

Comment: This reduced the run time by 100%! Since this only used one table scan compared to two in my query, I'm inclined to believe that the long pole is scanning the table. Can I use some index on date to make this scan faster?

Comment: @sat1017 it's worth to try an index on Date.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to SQL so I'm learning on the fly. What is the point of `MAX`? Shouldn't `CASE` return the `CloseAdjusted` price which is a positive value?

Comment: @sat1017 this is called conditional aggregation. The CASE expression inside MAX picks only 1 CloseAdjusted based on rn and this value is returned by MAX.

Comment: Does this work because when in the first case when rn does not equal 1 null or 0 is returned? So, therefore `MAX` will return the associated value of rn =1?

Comment: @sat1017 MAX does not return any value of rn. It returns the value of CloseAdjusted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239709/discussion-between-sat1017-and-forpas).